# Count occurrences of character in file -C

Tags: c, file, character

I have a text file with this format

```
Hello:Dad
How:Are
You:Today
```

I want to count how many times the colon appears in the file, for that I'm doing this function:

```
int NumColon(char txt[]) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(txt, "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }

    int count = 0;
    char ch;

    while (!feof(fp)) {
        ch = getc(fp);
        if (strcmp(&ch, ":") == 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

But when I print the value of the variable `count` it is on zero. However, if I do a `fprint("%s", &ch);` inside the `while` loop but before the `if` statement, I can clearly see that in certain moments the character obtained it's `:` so I don't understand what is happening and why isn't it getting inside the if statement of the loop.

EDIT: I've also tried using `if (ch == ':')` but still cannot get into the if statement.

Comment: Also see: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `ch` must be defined as `int` to handle `EOF` reliably.
- `while (!feof(fp))` is incorrect. Learn [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) You should instead write:

  ```
  while ((ch - getc(fp)) != EOF)
  ```
- `strcmp(&ch, ":")` is incorrect because `&ch` is not a C string. You should use `ch == ':'` instead.
- you forget to close the file, causing a resource leak.

Here is a modified version:

```
int NumColon(const char *filename) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    int count = 0;
    int c;
    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
        count += (c == ':');
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot! All your annotations made it work :)

Answer (score 1):

`strcmp` requires a string. A string is a NUL terminated sequence of characters. But `&ch` is a pointer to a single character and is not a string.

Do char compare instead: `if (ch == ':')`

Comment: Hi! Yes I had just modified it to strcmp, but my first attempt was with `if (ch == ':')` as you say and still didn't get into the if statement.

Comment: That would be a different issue. Please post a new question with that code. But for starters it would be good for you to do basic debugging. Run your program in a debugger and check the `ch` value to see if it is getting the values you expect, including the `':'`.

Comment: Detail: In C, `ch == ':'` is an `int` compare.